# How to Rollback MQ patching done on windows

Tags: ibm-mq

Could you please help on how to roll back the MQ patch applied on windows.

I have patched the system from MQ7.1.0.0 to MQ7.1.0.8. It is a MQ client.

Plz suggest how to rollback to 7.1.0.0.

```
dspmqver -i
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.1.0.8
Level:       p710-008-161121
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows
Mode:        32-bit
O/S:         Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Enterprise Edition, Build 7601: SP1
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
Primary:     Yes
MaxCmdLevel: 711

Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.1.0.0
InstName:    Installation2
InstDesc:
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1
Primary:     No
```

After executing the below command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin>dspmqver -i
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.1.0.8
Level:       p710-008-161121
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows
Mode:        32-bit
O/S:         Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Enterprise Edition, Build 7601: SP1
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc: InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
Primary:     No
MaxCmdLevel: 711

Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.1.0.0
InstName:    Installation2
InstDesc:
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1
Primary:     Yes
```

Comment: Note that you can highlight text in your question and click the icon with `{ }` above the editor to indent it four spaces, this lets it stay formatted the same as you pasted it.

Comment: Note that is is the `{}` icon, not the `"` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client software is distributed as a full install not a patch.  In your case the roll back would consist of a uninstall of the `7.1.0.8` client package and a reinstall of `7.1.0.0` client package.

Download links for each v7.1.0.x client package are located on the IBM page "[MQC71: WebSphere MQ V7.1 Clients](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412)".

NOTE that v7.1 of IBM MQ went out of support on April 30th 2017.  Newer versions of IBM MQ client can connect to IBM MQ Queue Managers that are at a older version.

---

You have two installations on the same server, `Installation1` is `7.1.0.8` and `Installation2` is `7.1.0.0`.  Because of the order of the installations, you probably upgraded `Installation1` from `7.1.0.0` to `7.1.0.8` and the later installed `7.1.0.0` as `Installation2`.

This is possible because MQ v7.1 and higher supports multiple versions being installed in parallel.  On Windows one installation will always be primary, in the original output you provided your `Installation1` at `7.1.0.8` was primary.

You can run the command below to switch the primary install to `Installation2` (your `7.1.0.0` installation).

```
setmqinst -i -n Installation2
```

The updated output you provided shows that `Installation2` at `7.1.0.0` is primary now.

You can consider this as rolled back to `7.1.0.0` since the installation with that version is now the Primary installation.  You could take it a step further and actually uninstall the `7.1.0.8` installation if you like or you could keep it in place to "roll forward" to in the future.

Comment: seeing the below inputs, please suggest how to rollback to MQ7.1.0.0.

Comment: based on **dspmqver -i** output, please suggest how to roll back. I'm not sure if it is client or server package. There is no Queue manager created, so I suppose it to be client.

Comment: Could you please verify the output from the question edited and let me know now if the application will be able to use Installation2 as it is set to primary now.

Comment: Atlast the issue is resolved after rolling back MQ, i.e., after setting the MQ7.1.0.0 version as primary. As always, thank you for your inputs. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell if it considered as a roll back or not? As I did not uninstall MQ7.1.0.8 but set the MQ7.1.0.0 as primary Installation.

Comment: @Rinak - dspmqinst can give details on the installs on a machine, and on windows includes the field "MSIMedia" which indicates whether you installed from a server or client media image. It sounds like you installed alongside, and are using primary to switch between versions of MQ - that is completely valid and one of the usecases of multiple installs. Once you are happy on the newer version, you can uninstall the older (non-primary) one. The alternative is an in-place upgrade, which replaces the old with the new, and rollback is to uninstall and reinstall in the same place.